# Shanon compression algorithm output Error

Tags: c

I am running the c code of Shannon-Fano compression algorithm. The program is compiling better but while executing, I get the segmentation fault (core dump) error. Similar questions have been already answered but I tried most of them but could not get sucess in resolving this error. please help me out. 
The program code is:

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
/***********************************************/
int Compress(int* input, int* output, int inputSize);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char* str = "This is an example for Shannon–Fano coding";
    printf("%s",str);
    int* originalData = originalData = (int*)str;
    int originalDataSize = strlen(str);

    int* compressedData = (int*)malloc(originalDataSize * (101 / 100) + 384);

    int compressedDataSize = Compress(originalData, compressedData, originalDataSize);
    return 0;
}
typedef struct {
int* BytePointer;
int BitPosition;
} BitStream;

typedef struct {
int Symbol;
int Count;
int Code;
int Bits;
} Symbol;

void initBitStream(BitStream* stream, int* buffer)
{
    stream->BytePointer = buffer;
    stream->BitPosition = 0;
}

void writeBits(BitStream* stream, int x, int bits)
{
    int* buffer = stream->BytePointer;
    int bit = stream->BitPosition;
    int mask = 1 << (bits - 1);

    for (int count = 0; count < bits; ++count)
    {
        *buffer = (*buffer & (0xff ^ (1 << (7 - bit)))) + ((x & mask ? 1 : 0) << (7 - bit));
        x <<= 1;
        bit = (bit + 1) & 7;

        if (!bit)
        {
            ++buffer;
        }
    }

    stream->BytePointer = buffer;
    stream->BitPosition = bit;
}

void histogram(int* input, Symbol* sym, int size)
{
    Symbol temp;
int i, swaps;

for (i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
{
    sym[i].Symbol = i;
    sym[i].Count = 0;
    sym[i].Code = 0;
    sym[i].Bits = 0;
}

for (i = size; i; --i)
{
    sym[*input++].Count++;
}

do
{
    swaps = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 255; ++i)
    {
        if (sym[i].Count < sym[i + 1].Count)
        {
            temp = sym[i];
            sym[i] = sym[i + 1];
            sym[i + 1] = temp;
            swaps = 1;
        }
    }
} while (swaps);
}

void makeTree(Symbol* sym, BitStream* stream, int code, int bits, int first, int last)
{
int i, size, sizeA, sizeB, lastA, firstB;

if (first == last)
{
    writeBits(stream, 1, 1);
    writeBits(stream, sym[first].Symbol, 8);
    sym[first].Code = code;
    sym[first].Bits = bits;
    return;
}
else
{
    writeBits(stream, 0, 1);
}

size = 0;

for (i = first; i <= last; ++i)
{
    size += sym[i].Count;
}

sizeA = 0;

for (i = first; sizeA < ((size + 1) >> 1) && i < last; ++i)
{
    sizeA += sym[i].Count;
}

if (sizeA > 0)
{
    writeBits(stream, 1, 1);

    lastA = i - 1;

    makeTree(sym, stream, (code << 1) + 0, bits + 1, first, lastA);
}
else
{
    writeBits(stream, 0, 1);
}

sizeB = size - sizeA;

if (sizeB > 0)
{
    writeBits(stream, 1, 1);

    firstB = i;

    makeTree(sym, stream, (code << 1) + 1, bits + 1, firstB, last);
}
else
{
    writeBits(stream, 0, 1);
}
}

int Compress(int* input, int* output, int inputSize)
{
Symbol sym[256], temp;
BitStream stream;
int i, totalBytes, swaps, symbol, lastSymbol;

if (inputSize < 1)
    return 0;

initBitStream(&stream, output);
histogram(input, sym, inputSize);

for (lastSymbol = 255; sym[lastSymbol].Count == 0; --lastSymbol);

if (lastSymbol == 0)
    ++lastSymbol;

makeTree(sym, &stream, 0, 0, 0, lastSymbol);

do
{
    swaps = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 255; ++i)
    {
        if (sym[i].Symbol > sym[i + 1].Symbol)
        {
            temp = sym[i];
            sym[i] = sym[i + 1];
            sym[i + 1] = temp;
            swaps = 1;
        }
    }
} while (swaps);

for (i = 0; i < inputSize; ++i)
{
    symbol = input[i];
    writeBits(&stream, sym[symbol].Code, sym[symbol].Bits);
}

totalBytes = (int)(stream.BytePointer - output);

if (stream.BitPosition > 0)
{
    ++totalBytes;
}

return totalBytes;
}
```

Comment: Time to [learn how to debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Use a debugger to catch the crash as and when it happens, and locate where it happens in your code and examine values of involved variables. Using tools like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is also very helpful.

Comment: And a general tip: Don't write large parts of code without intermediate testing. Write a *small* and *little* piece of code, build (with plenty of warnings enabled, that you treat as errors) and test. If it all works then you continue to the next small and little piece. That way it's *much* easier to figure out problems and where they might be. Also *always* have error checking and variable validation and bounds checking, even for things you "know" can't be wrong.

Comment: There are also some other problem with the code you show, like [casting `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858), or doing *integer* division (with `101 / 100` for example, which is *exactly* equal to the integer `1`).

Comment: I'd suspect that either you have a stack overflow because your recursion does not terminate properly, or that you are overrunning the end of your output buffer.  The rest of the code looks decent, although the sort implementation is horribly inefficient.

Comment: can you please help me in resolving the issue because I have attempted all my skills.